# Python how to press the #2 key twice and perform a separate action each time after press?

Tags: python, tkinter, keypress

I would like this code to run in a loop and for me to press the #2 key and each time it performs a separate action not similar to the first key press. I appreciate any and all help and thank you ahead of time!

```python
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def key(event):
    if event.keysym == 'q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p,a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,z,x,c,v,b,n,m':
        def read_number(path):
            print("do nothing")
    elif event.keysym =='2':
      print("Do first action")
        elif event.keysym =='2':
            print("Do another different action")
            # if event.keysym =='2':

root.bind_all('<Key>', key)
root.mainloop()
```

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def key(event):
    if event.keysym == 'q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p,a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,z,x,c,v,b,n,m':
        def read_number(path):
            print("hi")
    elif event.keysym =='2':
        if event.keysym =='2':
            print("Do another action")
            # if event.keysym =='2':

root.bind_all('<Key>', key)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can do whatever you want inside the block of `elif event.keysym == '2'`, so I wonder what your problem is actually. Also you do not state clear what *separate action* is.

Comment: 3 answers have been provided. Any of the 3 who provided answers would appreciate acceptance of their answer to acknowledge the question has been answered; or a comment if further clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a reasonable case for a state machine. A state machine allows you to based your next response on all of the previous inputs. Basically, you have to decide how many different states (different ways of interpreting the input) and what to do with all the different possible inputs in each of those cases.

I don't have a ton of time to write more, but here's a link to a Wikipedia article about state machines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

I would start there and see if you can figure out how something like that can help you. Maybe also look for some more tutorial descriptions. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

declare a boolean variable, and toggle it when first action runs. code would be like:

```
my_switch = True

elif event.keysym == '2' and my_switch:
  print("Do first action")
  my_switch = False

elif event.keysym == '2' and !(my_switch):
  print("Do second action")
  my_switch = True #only if you want the #2 key to have alternative functions, otherwise the key will do first action just once and then second one forever.
```

Comment: Does not work! The '&&" statement is not really Python and should be 'and' !

Comment: This is not the right code for Python!

Comment: Yes, `&&` should be `and` so I've updated my codes. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


def get_action():
    """ A generator function to return an action from a list of actions.

    A generator retains its state after being called. It yields 1 item per
    call. For example range() is generator.
    Functions with return statements initialize their state at each call.
    """
    actions = ["Do another action", 'action1', 'action2', 'action3',
               'action4']
    for i in range(len(actions)):
        """ The value of i is incremented each call. """
        yield actions[i]


def key(event):
    # if event.keysym == 'q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p,a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,z,x,c,v,b,n,m':
    # Changed the logic to display something when keys other than 2 are
    # pressed.
    if event.keysym in 'q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p,a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,z,x,c,v,b,n,m':
        print("hi")
        def read_number(path):
            pass
    elif event.keysym == '2':
        try:
            print(next(action))
        except StopIteration:
            # Action to take after the generator is expended.
            print('No more actions.')


action = get_action()  # Bind the generator to a name
root.bind_all('<Key>', key)
root.mainloop()
```